# Remove lines containing a string and change the value of lines left

Tags: c#, regex

I need a little help on removing some lines from multiple text files (50.000), containing a specified string, and then to change the value of lines left, in my case could be 0 lines or any random number.
Here is a sample code:

```
This is a test to remove lines containing a string:
//some other lines
0
0
//...

7
This line contains string "ONE"
This line contains string "2"
This line contains string "THREE", "9"
This line contains string "FOUR"
This line contains string "5"
This line contains string "SIX" , "ZERO"
This line contains string "SEVEN"
//more consecutive lines and 7 value from top, represents the number of lines that are following, until other function starts.

0
0
//...
```

This is a function in C# that i use to remove the lines:

```
foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(@"E:/WORK/Tests", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).AsParallel())
{
    string[] LinesToRemove = { "ONE", "2", "THREE", "FOUR", "5", "SIX", "SEVEN" };
    var query = File.ReadAllLines(f, Encoding.Unicode).Where(line => !LinesToRemove.Any(line.Contains));
    File.WriteAllLines(f, query, Encoding.Unicode);
}
```

7 , is the number of lines.
I want for example to remove all 7 lines (using string line remove) and move up 1 line and replace that 7 with a 0.
All lines are consecutive after that value 7.

Comment: "Remove the lines that contain any of those strings" and then do what exactly? That part is not clear at all. Please try to elaborate.

Comment: Remove all those 7 lines and that 7 must be 0. Or remove only 3 lines and that number of lines 7 becomes 4.
But right now i need to remove all 7 lines and to change(replace) that 7 with 0.

Comment: So, do you provide the number (7 or 3) as an input parameter or is it determined based on something? Also, your code doesn't do anything to check if the removed lines are consecutive. Are they all always consecutive or do they exist in chunks? Do they always have their count in the preceding line? Please [edit] the question, provide clear description of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: 7 represent the number of lines after that 7, and yes, lines are always consecutive. A program read that 7 value and expects to execute 7 lines.
I need to remove the lines and replace that 7 with a 0.

Comment: Basically, after removing all seven lines, to move up one line and replace that 7 with a 0.
Works with regex, i can replace everything, including the 7 value , with a 0. But is very slow and wrong, is writing one 0 for every lines read.

Comment: This is regex i tried: https://regex101.com/r/4rzCOb/1
The result is: 0000000
Seven zeroes :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was fun.

Here you go.

```
foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(@"E:/WORK/Tests", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).AsParallel())
{
    string[] LinesToRemove = { "ONE", "2", "THREE", "FOUR", "5", "SIX", "SEVEN" };
    string[] linesInFile = File.ReadAllLines(f);
    List<string> newFileLines = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < linesInFile.Length;)
    {
        int n;
        bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(linesInFile[i], out n);
        if (isNumeric && n > 0)
        {
            List<string> tempLines = new List<string>();
            int remainingLines = 0;
            int m = i + n + 1;
            for (int y = i + 1; y < m; y++)
            {
                if(y >= linesInFile.Length)
                {
                    break; //I think this should work since i haven't checked
                    // Or something like i++; break;

                }

                if (!LinesToRemove.Any(s => linesInFile[y].Contains(s)))
                {
                    tempLines.Add(linesInFile[y]);
                    remainingLines++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            i++;
            newFileLines.Add(remainingLines.ToString());
            newFileLines.AddRange(tempLines);
        }
        else
        {
            newFileLines.Add(linesInFile[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    File.WriteAllLines(f, newFileLines);
}
```

Comment: This works, and super fast :).I want to study your code now.
Thanks!

Comment: I am getting an error when trying to do many files:
"System.IndexOutOfRangeException
  HResult=0x80131508
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array."

At this line:
```
if (!LinesToRemove.Any(s => linesInFile[y].Contains(s)))
```

Comment: Add this outside everything `string currentFile = "" and `int currentLine = 0`, then at start of `foreach file` add `currentFile = f`, before each `i++` add `currentLine = i` and also wrap whole foreach loop inside `try/catch` (do not wrap `currentFile`). Inside `catch` add something like `var asd = currentFile; var ddd = currentLine` After you that, when error comes you will have in which file at which line it occured. Give that file to me so i can see where is the problem (or see it yourself)

Comment: @noAddiction oh i get where problem can occur. If file have for example 2 lines like this `3` and `Second Line` my code will try to irritate for 3 lines since i do not check for that fault... check edit in 3 min

Comment: Works now! I just did 55.000 files :)
If i encounter any other problem, i'll try to fix it myself, don't want to bother you too much.
Thanks again!